# Is it possible to make multiple css sheets from single layout-scss page, and multiple variable-scss sheets?

Tags: sass

I'm attempting to integrate scss with the .net theming functionality.

Ideally most scss would be in a dedicated directory, but each theme would have its own scss page containing exclusively the variable values for that particular theme.

The problem I'm encountering is that I need to pass placeholder variables to the _layout.scss sheet, and then have their values updated by the theme scss sheets. Currently the original null values are outputted.

## SCSS Files

---

***Resources/SCSS/_variables.scss***

```
$theme_color: null;
```

***Resources/SCSS/_layout.scss***

```
@import "variables";

div {
color: $theme_color;
}
```

***Themes/Blue/blue.scss***

```
$theme_color: #0000ff !default;

@import '../../Resources/SCSS/layout';
```

***Themes/Red/red.scss***

```
$theme_color: #ff0000 !default;

@import '../../Resources/SCSS/layout';
```

## Desired CSS Output Files

---

***blue.css***

```
div {
color: #0000ff;
}
```

***red.css***

```
div {
color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it backwards.  The `!default` flag tells Sass that this is the value to use if it doesn't a previous declaration doesn't exist.

```
$foo: red;
$foo: blue !default;

@debug $foo; // red

$bar: red !default;
$bar: blue;

@debug $bar; // blue
```

You need to place the `!default` flag on the default null values, not the theme values.

Comment: Well that was simpler than I anticipated. Thank you!